# Хранение ключей от программы

Tags: python, auth

Делаю программу на Python, в которой нужно будет вводить ключ для авторизации.
Только где их хранить?
Firebase не вариант, так как там идёт авторизация через email.
Нужно чтобы никто не пробрался к ним.

Comment: гугл диск с доступом по ссылке?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Ключ для авторизации чего? Кто знает и вводит ключ? Приложение десктоп или серверное?